# Lins2SD app error: could not load library libsigchain.so. What does it mean?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, link2sd

I've a Lenovo A 7000 (64-bit) Android mobile.  While using [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en) app on my rooted mobile, I observed an error after trying to move an app to SD. It says:

> WARNING: linker: could not load library "libsigchain.so" from LD_PRELOAD for "/system/bin/sh";  caused by "libsigchain.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit  CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE:....

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 1):

PM the app developers and tell them to add this to their app:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib64:/system/lib
```

The Link2Sd dev fixed this in the latest beta (`Link2SD-release-4.0.12.beta5`).

Answer (score 0):

It basically means that some binary code cannot be executed on your phone. It appears the Link2SD app you use comes with a piece of 32bit software, but your phone is 64bit so it cannot execute the code.

`LD_PRELOAD` is a system variable which basically tells Android what code libraries should be loaded/executed when starting any process or app. It appears `libsigchain.so` was added to this variable, possibly by the Link2SD app itself. When the app tries to execute the system program `/system/bin/sh`, it tries to load the `libsigchain.so` file but fails, apparently because `libsigchain.so` is 32bit.

Another possible cause is that `/system/bin/sh` is 64bit but `ligsigchain.so` is 32bit. Because 32bit and 64bit software operate in a different way, the two can not be combined and the `/system/bin/sh` process cannot start and produces an error.

Either way, not being able to execute `sh` is a mayor problem for most apps working with root permissions as `sh` is used to execute scripts on your device. If you see such an error in other root-apps as well, this might be a problem with your Android ROM.

The solution to this might be either a software update from Lenovo or from a new version of the app. Try reporting the issue to the app developer, maybe he/she can give you the exact details.